# Parse a xml file and fetch the value from the elements which has same name using powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

Here I am trying to get the each version element value into different variables using powershell script. How can I achieve this. My xml file data looks like below values.

[image]

I want parse this xml file and need to save the 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 values into different variable or I need to insert these values into an array. Please help me out.

What I tried ?

```
[xml]$fileContent = Get-Content FilePath.xml
$ver = $fileContent.root.versions.version
if I print the $ver, I am getting all the version together i.e 2.1 2.2 2.3
```

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/503046) of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ver` is an array of strings, so you can index it using angle brackets:

```powershell
if( $ver.Count -ge 3 ) {   # Make sure we have at least 3 elements
    $v1 = $ver[0]
    $v2 = $ver[1]
    $v3 = $ver[2]
}
```